# Difference between “function with return” and “function without return”

Tags: javascript

How to access to inner function by js. In other word, what's difference between “function with return” and “function without return”?

**with return**

```
function makeAdder(x) {

    function add(y) {
       console.log(x,y)
       return x+y;
    };

    return add;

}

makeAdder(3)(4)   // 7
```

**without**

```
function makeAdder(x) {

    function add(y) {
       console.log(x,y)
       return x+y;
    };
}

makeAdder(3)(4)   // error
```

If I want to access `add()` like `makeAdder(3).add(4)`,how to code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function has no `return` statement, it implicitly returns `undefined`. If you want to call `.add` like you described, your function should return an object with an `add` property:

```js
function makeAdder(x) {
    return {
      add(y) {
        return x+y;
      }
    };
}

console.log(makeAdder(3).add(4))   // 7
```

Alternatively, you could also use [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for a more traditional OO approach:

```js
class Adder {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x  
  }
  
  add(y) {
    return this.x + y
  }
}

console.log(new Adder(3).add(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

`makeAdder` should return `object` in that case!

When `makeAdder(3)` is called, it returns `object` having key as `add` which holds a function.

```js
function makeAdder(x) {
  function add(y) {
    console.log(x, y)
    return x + y;
  };
  return {
    add: add
  };
}

console.log(makeAdder(3).add(4));
```